# Cannot login after running startx and rebooting

Tags: xorg, login, vmware, logout

Yesterday I tested `startx`, and in user root(admin) I went to x-window system.
After this I shutdown Linux by **power off virtual machine vmware button**. Today, when I turn on Linux in the virtual machine, **I cannot login as root anymore**, only as guest. When I try to login as root, I get stuck at the login page... I am sure my password is correct. I can still login as guest user. How can I fix this?

This is the only thing I typed yesterday:

```
startx
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: anyone can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: at the login screen, press control+alt+F3.
Step 2: type `sudo rm .Xauthority`

at the login.
Step 3: run `sudo reboot`

you should be able to login now.

To prevent this from happining again, **DO NOT RUN STARTX as root!**

this will make the .Xauthority file owned by *root*.
If the .Xauthority file is gone, root will not have it.

Comment: Your are welcome! seemed to earn a bounty or something! cool.

Comment: I had to do the same for `.ICEauthority` file as well.